# Guava generic for Ordering

Tags: java, generics, collections, guava

I have quite big issue with create generic method for Ordering. At this moment I have this function :

```
public <T> T orderAscending(Function<?, ? extends Comparable> function, Iterable<? extends LinkedList<?>> sortingList) {
    return Ordering.natural().onResultOf(function).sortedCopy(sortingList);
}
```

First parameter of this function is created in this way :

```
public static Function<ParkingWebApiDTO, Date> getSortActiveParkingsByStartDate() {
        Function<ParkingWebApiDTO, Date> getStartDateFunction = new Function<ParkingWebApiDTO, Date>() {
            @Override
            public Date apply(ParkingWebApiDTO parkingWebApiDTO) {
                return parkingWebApiDTO.getStartDate();
            }
        };
        return getStartDateFunction;
    }
```

and the second one is LinkedList with some custom object in it (`List<MyObject> test = new LinkedList<MyObject>()`).

Please someone help me to fix this generic method `orderAscending`. Much appreciated for help.

Comment: You forgot to mention what the actual issue is...

Comment: Compilation issue :)

Comment: Could you then share with us the compilation error? It's probably another problem with generic type inference. Or it could be that the result of `sortedCopy()` (a `List<T>`, from the `Iterable<T>` input) is returned as a `T`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant to create `List` (sorted by start date) from `Iterable` of your DTOs (I assume you don't want iterable of lists of DTOs).

So let's say your DTO looks like this:

```
interface ParkingWebApiDTO { // could be simple class, etc.
  Date getStartDate();
  // ...and more methods here
}
```

you have input list:

```
LinkedList<? extends ParkingWebApiDTO> iterable = Lists.newLinkedList();
```

and function which retrieves start date from DTO:

```
Function<ParkingWebApiDTO, Date> function = new Function<ParkingWebApiDTO, Date>() {
  @Override
  public Date apply(ParkingWebApiDTO dto) {
    return dto.getStartDate();
  }
};
```

you expect output like this:

```
List<? extends ParkingWebApiDTO> result = orderAscending(function, iterable);
```

which can be achieved with **following `orderAscending` imlementation**:

```
public static <X, T extends Comparable<T>> List<? extends X> orderAscending(
    Function<X, T> function, Iterable<? extends X> sortingList) {
  return Ordering.natural().onResultOf(function).sortedCopy(sortingList);
}
```

You need to declare both from and to types as generic types if you want to have "universal" method.

Another thing is if you really *need* to have such generic name, because using `Ordering.natural().onResultOf(function).sortedCopy(list)` is perfectly fine and having `orderAscending` is IMO overkill (you'll end with plenty of methods like this one).